# SUM no realiza suma correcta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una tabla que contiene esta informacion

| NoCredito | Nombre Cliente | Cumple | Cumple3Meses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 0 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 |

y quiero agregar un campo llamado Conteo3Meses, este es el resultado que espero

| NoCredito | Nombre Cliente | Cumple | Cumple3Meses | Conteo3Meses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 | 3 |

sin embargo al realizar un SUM como lo estoy haciendo aca

```
SELECT 
NoCredito,
NombreCliente,
Cumple,
Cumple3Meses,
SUM(Cumple3Meses) Conteo3Meses

FROM Lista

WHERE NoCredito = '0300022255'
```

Me sale este resultado, no me suma ese 0

| NoCredito | Nombre Cliente | Cumple | Cumple3Meses | Conteo3Meses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 0300022255 | NORA ESNESTINA | 1 | 1 | 3 |

Como puedo hacer para obtener el resultado que quiero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta de la siguiente manera:

```sql
with suma as ( 
select sum(Cumple3Meses) suma
from tabla
where nrocredito = '0300022255'
)

select tabla.*
from tabla, suma
```